# Taskbar Disappearing on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, modern-ui

It seems that the taskbar disappears permanently whenever I use certain Metro apps on Windows 8.1. That is, when I exit the app, the taskbar is gone from the screen that the Metro app appeared on (yet, it always stays on my other monitor). The only way I am able to resolve to the issue seems to be by restarting entirely. Needless to say, this is a real pain.

Is there any way I can prevent this (short of not using Windows Store apps)? If not, is there a better way to fix this problem once the taskbar disappears (better than restarting)?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/the-task-bar-is-missing-on-windows-8/5775e807-5fe4-42bf-b39a-5fe33451f169

Answer (score 8):

Restart explorer instead of restarting computer and see if it works.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open Task Manager.
2. Right click Windows Explorer, restart.

This will close your active explorer windows though.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution for Taskbar and icons that disappear:

1. Go to Task Manager
2. Right click on Explorer, Properties
3. Go to Security tab, click Advanced
4. Change ownership to Everyone. Check all permissions boxes.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out that the antivirus system has adopted explorer.exe as a threat???!!! and it was placed in the folder of blocked list and quarantined items. The removal from there solves the problem.

Comment: This is commentary and does not really answer the author's question

Comment: Ramhound you can give me negative assessments all you want, but none of the answers suggested above did solve my problem. It only was temporarily masked. So I decided to look for myself why and report the outcome to help someone else. Happy New Year to all.